# C - While loop not exiting how expected with string input

Tags: c, do-while

I want to exit my do-while loop when the user enters "exit" from the command line. I'm trying to do it without using strcmp() but it's just not performing how I think it should. When testing it if the user enters e for the first character, or x for the second character, or i for the third, or t for the fourth character then the program exits. It's probably something simple that I'm missing. So can anyone explain why this isn't working how I'm expecting? Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define FLUSH while(getchar() != '\n');

int main(){
    char input[20] = {0};

    printf("This is a string math program. Enter a string 9 characters or less"
                " followed by an operater and finally another string 9 characters or less."
                " There should be no spaces entered. To exit the program type exit.\n");

    do{
        printf("Input: ");
        scanf("%s",input);

        FLUSH



    } while((input[0] != 'e') && (input[1] != 'x') && (input[2] != 'i') && (input[3] != 't'));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's talk about [De Morgan's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws).  This:

```
(input[0] != 'e') && (input[1] != 'x') && (input[2] != 'i') && (input[3] != 't')
```

is required to be true for your loop to continue.  It is equivalent to this:

```
!(input[0] == 'e' || input[1] == 'x' || input[2] == 'i' || input[3] == 't')
```

So yes, your loop will stop when any character matches.  Just use strcmp, but if you can't for some bizarre reason, just change the above logic.

Comment: You answered faster than I could, but I would add that the OP could test to see if all conditions are true similar to the second case you described, with `!(input[0]=='e' && input[1]=='x' && input[2]=='i' && input[3] == 't')`

Comment: Alright thank you. It makes sense now why it wasn't working when thinking about De Morgan's Law. And I'm not supposed to use strcmp because it's for an assignment in school.